# How do I reduce the space between the elements in html?

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the blank space between a header and a table  but I don't know how.
I've marked the spot on the screenshot.

[image]

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>SPLETNA STRAN</h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="stran1.html"> STRAN 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="stran2.html"> STRAN 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="stran3.html"> STRAN 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="stran4.html"> STRAN 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="stran5.html"> STRAN 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you doing anything to remove the bottom margin on the h1 element?

Comment: When you inspect the element with browser console tools you can see the header has margin on it.

Comment: it's probably because of css file you have included or because of browser imposed css file, just make `margin:0` for the header and table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only give you a guess.

```
h1, ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just add for instance `margin-top:-20px;`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
  background-color: #333;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin-top:-20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Spletna stran</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


</head>
<body>

<h1>SPLETNA STRAN</h1>

<ul>
<li><a href="stran1.html"> STRAN 1</a></li>
<li><a href="stran2.html"> STRAN 2</a></li>
<li><a href="stran3.html"> STRAN 3</a></li>
<li><a href="stran4.html"> STRAN 4</a></li>
<li><a href="stran5.html"> STRAN 5</a></li>
</ul> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A common culprit with extra spacing would be the line-height:; property. Try setting `line-height: 0;`.
            also if you don't already have a CSS reset sheet definitely look into getting one in order to zero out your browsers preset styles. Here's what I am using https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

it's probably because of user agent style sheet add [reset.css](https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6) to override them also if you want you can just modify the `style.css` which you linked, just update/add this to your code.

```
ul {
margin-top:0; }
h1 {
margin-botton:0; }
```